# What does absolute parameter do in DateTime::diff(DateTime [, bool absolute = false])

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

Here is the sample code

```
$c = new DateTime();
$o = clone $c;
$o->modify('-60 days');
$diff = $c->diff($o);
$diff2 = $c->diff($o, TRUE);
var_dump($diff, $diff2);
```

which outputs

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (8) {
  ["y"]=> int(0), ["m"]=> int(1), ["d"]=> int(29), ["h"]=> int(0), ["i"]=> int(0),
  ["s"]=> int(0), ["invert"]=> int(1), ["days"]=> int(60)
}
object(DateInterval)#4 (8) {
  ["y"]=> int(0), ["m"]=> int(1), ["d"]=> int(29), ["h"]=> int(0), ["i"]=> int(0),
  ["s"]=> int(0), ["invert"]=> int(0), ["days"]=> int(60)
}
```

as I see, only the "invert" property changes. What does this mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The absolute property will return the absolute difference between two DateTime objects. This will change the result to positive when a negative difference is returned.

Comment: thanks, I get it now. Tested it with `echo $diff->format('%R%a'), $diff2->format('%R%a');` which yields `-60+60` //darn the time limit to accept answers :(

Answer (score -1):

From php.net

```
Absolute parameter determines whether to return absolute difference.
```

LOI  [datetime.diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)